# Selected Value based on another salected value - Salesforce APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, selectedvalue

I have visualforce page like this

```
                        <apex:selectList label="Food" multiselect="true" value="{!selectedFood}" size="5">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!FoodList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:selectList label="Area" value="{!selectedDetailFood}" multiselect="true" size="5">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!DetailFoodList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
```

and the apex class like this.

```
    public List<selectOption> getFoodList(){
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    options.add( new selectOption('', '--select--') );
    options.add( new selectOption('Warm Food', 'Warm Food') );
    options.add( new selectOption('Cold Food', 'Cold Food') );
    return options;
}
    public List<selectOption> getDetailFoodList(){
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    options.add( new selectOption('', '--select--') );
    options.add( new selectOption('Ramen', 'Ramen') );
    options.add( new selectOption('Soto', 'Soto') );
    options.add( new selectOption('Frozen Mix Salad', 'Frozen Mix Salad') );
    return options;

}
```

Selection 1 have value = warm food, cold food (Static Value *Hardcode not from soql) and the other selection have value based on value that i choose in selection 1, example if i choose warm food in selection 1, the value that will show in selection 2 is ramen and soto.(Static Value *Hardcode not from soql)

is it possible make it in apex and visualforce salesforce? if it so how to make it? thank you